# Auto-Populate Google Apps Hangouts Roster?

Tags: google-workspace

I want every user in my organization to have every other user in their Hangouts roster. Is there a way to do this, or even a way to manually populate those rosters for them to give them a starting point?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is possible. But if I remember correctly you could create a circle with all users and share that with all users